# Are there any thread specific clocks in the C++ world?

Tags: c++

I used to measure time consumption of different threads with `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` and `clock_gettime`.

But clock_gettime is a standard in POSIX world, so it won't work in other platform like Windows when it comes to platform crossing.

I checked the C++ STD, found `steady_clock`, `system_clcok`, `high_resolution_clock` till now, none of these can clock a specific thread.

Did I miss any thing? If yes, what's the bullet? Or if not, any advices?

Comment: Better if you can give a more detailed exp. as answer. @JoachimPileborg

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You could post it in the appropriate place, though, rather than in the comments section. Then it can be peer reviewed like any other answer, which was the entire purpose of the creation of SO's model over more "forum"-like websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to abstract out implementation of your thread timer, under windows you can use [GetThreadTimes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683237%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function. Under linux (or non POSIX) use CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID. But I suppose if you compile with mingw under windows then CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID will be available.

Also, for portability take a look at boost [thread_clock](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/chrono/reference.html#chrono.reference.other_clocks.thread_clock_hpp.thread_clock)

Answer (score 2):

The only "clock" to measure CPU time in the C++ standard is [std::clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock), which doesn't measure CPU time in Windows so it's still not portable, and anyway it's per process and not per thread.

If you want to measure thread CPU time you have to resort to non-portable platform-specific functions.